# Django template renderer reorders div and table elements, breaking a jquery library

Tags: django

I'm using Django 1.6 along with the django-formset-js library extension to dynamically resize formsets with JQuery on the client-side.  This library requires you to wrap certain elements of your forms in named divs.

I expect to produce one table with all my forms inside of it.  According to the documentation and prior experience, using `{{ form.as_table }}` will render the form as a set of `<tr>...</tr>` table rows (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#form-rendering-options).

However, Django renders the HTML in such a way that my wrapping divs are empty and mismatched.  The divs are also moved outside of the table instead of wrapping the appropriate `<tr>...</tr>` rows.  Why is the renderer behaving this way with table forms, when the problem does not reproduce with `{{ form.as_p }}` or `{{ form.as_ul }}`?

#### Template:

```html
<form>
  <div id="formset" data-formset-prefix="{{ view.form.prefix }}">
    <!-- .... -->      
    <table>
      <div data-formset-body="">
        {% for form in view.form %}
        <div data-formset-form="">
          {{ form.as_table }}
          <tr>
            <td>
              <button data-formset-delete-button="" type="button" >Delete form</button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
      </div>
      <!--  .... -->     
    </table>
  </div>
</form>
```

#### Rendered HTML:

```html
<form>
  <div id="formset" data-formset-prefix="...">
    <div data-formset-body="">
      <div data-formset-form="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div data-formset-form="">
    </div>
    <div data-formset-form="">
    </div>
    <table>
      <!-- all the forms end up here -->
      <tr>...</tr> 
      <tr>...</tr>           
      <tr>...</tr> 
    </table>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, this is actually a rookie HTML error on my part.  I was thinking of `<div>` like a set of curly braces instead of an element of the render tree (which it actually is).

Having investigated further, I found that mixing `<div>` and `<table>` is a violation of HTML standards and will lead to undefined behavior.  Specifically:

> "One important thing to remember when putting a div inside of a table is that the div needs to live inside of a particular table cell, meaning inside of a td element which is inside of a tr or th element."
>   (http://css-tricks.com/using-divs-inside-tables/)

It follows that Django's separation of the divs from the table is probably done intentionally in a validation pass or something similar.  Also, `<span>` behaves exactly the same as `<div>` here, so that is not a solution.

I can rectify the problem by wrapping each form in its own table, with the table fully enclosed within the div.  The template is then rendered into valid HTML and works as expected:

#### Template:

```
<form>
  <div id="formset" data-formset-prefix="{{ view.form.prefix }}">
    <!-- .... -->      
    <div data-formset-body="">
      {% for form in view.form %}
      <div data-formset-form="">
        <table>
          {{ form.as_table }}
          <tr>
            <td>
              <button data-formset-delete-button="" type="button" >Delete form</button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <!--  .... -->     
  </div>
</form>
```